# RMagick quality does not work for to_blob

Tags: resize, imagemagick, blob, rmagick

I am trying to resize an image and reduce the quality of an image pulled from a database and be able to save it back into the database at the reduced size.

So far, I am trying the following RMagick methods:

```
image = Image.from_blob(origImage.data).first do
        self.format = "png"
      end
      image.resize_to_fit!(width)
      image.quality = 60
      newImage = image.to_blob
```

But the value of **image.quality** has no implact on the size of data from **to_blob**.

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the quality argument on the to_blob method instead.

```
# image.quality = 60 # ignore this
newImage = image.to_blob { self.quality = 60 }
```

You're probably outputting the same format as origImage there -- `format` doesn't appear to work in `from_blob`. I had to specifically call it after the `from_blob` line to set the PNG format.

```
image = Magick::Image.from_blob(origImage.data).first do
#    self.format = 'PNG'
end
image.format = 'PNG'
```